# Outlook Add-In Ribbon button that is always active

Tags: outlook-addin

How to define Outlook Add-In manifest so that the Add-In Ribbon button is always active regardless of if an mail or calendar item is selected? Insights add-in provided by Microsoft is doing it somehow as it is always active, while the Report Message add-in button is only active when an item is selected.

[image]

The Rule element is mandatory, and there is no "wildcard" to always enable the Add-In via Rules at least, so there is probably some other way.

```
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>
```

Current manifest:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want the Add-in button to be enabled even when no item is selected in mailbox?

Comment: Yes. "How to define Outlook Add-In manifest so that the Add-In Ribbon button is always active regardless of if an mail or calendar item is selected?"

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature of **enabling an add-in without selecting an item,** you requested, is not a part of the product.
We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues). Please add your request here with the label “Type: product feature request”.
Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.